# analisar HTML como PHP com Htaccess

Tags: php, html, apache

Eu tenho um site html e quero páginas HTML para ser analisado como php; Eu estou usando um arquivo .htaccess para isso.

No servidor localhost, ele funciona corretamente. O comando é:

AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .html .htm

No entanto, no servidor online não funciona . Quando eu acesso a página, ela pede para baixar o arquivo em vez de exibir a página.

Eu estou usando PHP 5.5 a Versão do Apache e Apache/2.4.10
 tenho varios includes php dentro do html mais para isso teria que mudar todas as paginas para .php mais iria dar muito trabalho então quero deixar tudo com .html mais executando os includes mas so que o codigo nao funciona no servidor online

Eu tentei todos os tipos de comandos semelhantes em htaccess, como:

- AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm
- AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .html .htm
- AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .html .htm
- AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .html .htm
- AddHandler x-mapp-php .html .htm
- AddHandler x-mapp-php5 .html .htm

mas sem sorte.

Eu também tentei

- RemoveHandler .html .htm mas sem sucesso.

Eu verifiquei no servidor se o .htaccess esta ativo e esta testei um codigo e funcionou normal o problema esta no codigo mesmo

Comment: Se criar um `.php` ele roda normalmente?  Porque não renomeia todos os arquivos, do tipo `rename -S .html .php *.html`, por exemplo.

Answer (score 0):

Edite ou crie o arquivo com o nome **.htaccess** dentro do directório onde estão os arquivos html e coloque o seguinte comando:

Para servidores linux SuPHP:
`AddHandler php-script html`

Para servidores linux que NÃO forem SuPHP:
`AddType application/x-httpd-php .html`

Comment: mesmo assim nao deu certo continua o erro

Comment: estranho, voce usa o cpanel?

Comment: NO **cPanel** também pode alterar isso na secção **MIME Types**

Comment: ja vi tambem mas o erro continua eu troquei de servidor fui pro hostgator e la deu certo ta funcionando normal acho que o problema era o outro servidor usei o AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .html e deu certo mesmo assim obrigado ai pela ajuda

Comment: Pois tinha que ser algo com a config do servidor ;)